# How to stop software updater from disabling Nvidia driver?

Tags: nvidia

I am running Ubuntu 14.05.  Every time I reboot after a 2-3 days or a week, the Nvidia driver is disabled because of the automatic software updates.  Is it possible to configure the automatic software updater to NOT disable the Nvidia driver?  Thank you.

Comment: You posted the same question, worded slightly differently, three times in a five minute period. It's tiresome to flag all of them as duplicate questions requiring the same answer accepted by >200 votes.

Comment: They absolutely are not the same question.  They are three different questions about three different ways to resolve the same problem.

Comment: And I got zero correct answers.  Seems I should have worded the question more precisely, which I now will.

Comment: How did you install the Nvidia graphics driver? The installation method has an impact on whether the driver is rebuilt automatically for each new kernel upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a new kernel in an update, the nvidia driver needs to be rebuilt for the new module.  You need to fix your build environment, something is missing.  List the nvidia packages you have with

```
dpkg -l |grep nvidia
```

and then for the driver, (nvidia-361 in the below example) get the packages it depends upon:

```
apt-cache depends nvidia-361
The output looks like:
nvidia-361
  Depends: x11-common
  Depends: make
    make-guile
  Depends: sed
    sed:i386
  Depends: dkms
  Depends: linux-libc-dev
  Depends: libc6-dev
  Depends: patch
    patch:i386
  Depends: acpid
  Depends: lib32gcc1
  Depends: libc6-i386
  Depends: passwd
    passwd:i386
  Depends: adduser
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: <libgl1>
    libgl1-mesa-glx
  Depends: libx11-6
  Depends: libxext6
...snip
```

install the missing ones and the kernel updates should not longer break things.

---

When you run an older kernel, is Nvidia still broken?
What driver are you running when not running Nvidia? (nouveau?)
If nouveau, check for the line  "blacklist nouveau" in any file in /etc/modprobe.d

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu installs a new kernel every few days. I think it is the regular updates seeing he is using an older package and updating with the current package which he doesn't want to happen. I think freezing the package at the current version (he picked) is what he wants. I could have misread his situation though...

Comment: I can't do all that because this machine is not on the internet.  I merely want to re-enable the Nvidia driver that I already installed and that was already working correctly before the ubuntu software updater broke everything.

Comment: If you are not on the internet, how do you get the updates?

Comment: This machine was on the internet previously.  It received updates.  Then I moved.  Then I rebooted.  I only realized that Ubuntu broke the Nvidia configuration after I moved.  The new location has no internet access.  So now this machine is no longer on the internet.